# What is the best way to do split() in javascript and ignore blank entries?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, string, split

I have the following C# code that i need to convert to javascript:

```
    static private string[] ParseSemicolon(string fullString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullString))
            return new string[] { };

        if (fullString.IndexOf(';') > -1)
        {
            return fullString.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(str => str.Trim()).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return new[] { fullString.Trim() };
        }
    }
```

i see that javascript has a split() function as well but i wanted to see if there is built in support for the other checks or i have to do an additional loop around the array afterwards to "clean up" the data?

Comment: maybe you can replace ";;" with ";" in the string beforehand?

Comment: @Wilmer what about ;;; or ;;;; etc

Comment: would have to be in a loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but this function is implemented only in more recent browsers.

```
"dog;in;bin;;cats".split(";").filter(function (x) { return x != ""; });
```

Comment: Shorter version: `"dog;in;bin;;cats".split(";").filter(Boolean)` :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) to split on any consecutive count of the delimiter:

```
var parts = input.split(/;+/);
```

Such as:

```
var input = "foo;;;bar;;;;;;;;;baz";
var parts = input.split(/;+/);

console.log(parts);
// [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]
```

Comment: ";foo;;;bar;;;;;;;;;baz;" -> [";","foo","bar","baz",";"], some how need value to be trimed

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
"hello;aamir;;afridi".split(';').filter(Boolean)
```

or

```
"hello;;aamir;;;;afridi".split(';').filter(Boolean)
```

results in

```
["hello", "aamir", "afridi"]
```

And to convert it back to string, use this

```
"hello;aamir;;afridi".split(';').filter(Boolean).join(' ')
```

or

```
"hello;aamir;;afridi".split(';').filter(Boolean).join(';')
```

Answer (score 1):

Split also requires handling the empty results.
However, where's another way

http://jsfiddle.net/9mHug/1/

```
var str = "aaa,bbb;ccc  ddd , eee";
var sp = str.match(/\w+/g);
alert(sp);
```

This will give you a clean array of only the words.
`\w` is a regex search that will find all letters of certain type `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately javascript split() does not check for doublespaces etc, you would need to clean up your array later

```
var str = "How;are;;you;my;;friend?";
var arr = str.split(";");

alert(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p58qm/2/

You can then update the array with this loop

```
len = arr.length, i;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++ )
arr[i] && arr.push(arr[i]);  // copy non-empty values to the end of the array

arr.splice(0 , len);

alert(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p58qm/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function parseSemicolon(fullString) {
    var result = new Array();
    if (!!fullString && fullString.length > 0) {
        fullString = fullString.trim();
        if (fullString.indexOf(';') > -1) {
            result = fullString.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                result[i] = result[i].trim();
            }
        } else {
            result = new Array(fullString);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This should have exactly the same effect as your C# script.